# Calculating SQL score depending on join table

Tags: mysql, sql, mapreduce

I have 3 tables :

`Users`

```
| id  | name  |
---------------
| 1   | Bob   |
| 2   | Dylan |
| 3   | Jenna |
```

`Friendships`, which is a join table for friendship relation

```
| user1_id | user2_id |
-----------------------
|    1     |    2     | // Bob and Dylan are friends
|    2     |    3     | // Dylan and Jenna are friends
```

And `Posts`

```
| id   | user_id  | title           | content |
-----------------------------------------------
|  1   |    1     | Bob's post      |   ...   |
|  2   |    2     | Dylan's post    |   ...   |
|  3   |    3     | Jenna's post    |   ...   |
```

I want to calculate each post score, with the score formula as follows :

```
score = (is_post_author_friend_of_user(X)) ? 2 : 1
```

Where X is an user_id.
Is it possible to achieve such calculation in pure SQL ? That implies retrieving the many to many relation data, of course.
If yes, is it fitted for the job ? What about map/reduce for such case ? I might be using terms I don't fully understand.

### Examples for clarity

If Bob requests to see all posts, the scores will be as follows:

```
| id   | user_id  | title           | content | score |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |    1     | Bob's post      |   ...   |   1   |
|  2   |    2     | Dylan's post    |   ...   |   2   |
|  3   |    3     | Jenna's post    |   ...   |   1   |
```

Because Bob is only friend with Dylan.
But if Dylan do the same request, the scores will be:

```
| id   | user_id  | title           | content | score |
-------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |    1     | Bob's post      |   ...   |   2   |
|  2   |    2     | Dylan's post    |   ...   |   1   |
|  3   |    3     | Jenna's post    |   ...   |   2   |
```

Because Dylan is friend with both Bob and Jenna.

Comment: what does the formula mean?

Comment: If the post is posted by a friend (= an entry is on the friends table referencing both the client user_id and the poster user_id), then the score is 2. Else it is 1.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Does the friend table work both ways? If user1_id is friends with user2_id, is user2_id also friends with user1_id?

Comment: @Bob Yes it works both ways. I added examples as requested for clarity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe this is possible in pure SQL.

You can try this - it might not be the fastest, but it seems to work for me.

```
select
  p.id,
  p.user_id,
  p.title,
  p.content,
  count(f.user1_id) + 1
from
  Posts p
left outer join
  Friendships f
  on (f.user1_id = p.user_id and f.user2_id = 2) -- change the 2 to the requesting id.
  or (f.user2_id = p.user_id and f.user1_id = 2) -- change the 2 to the requesting id.
group by
  p.id,
  p.user_id,
  p.title,
  p.content
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f72f/7)

I'm not sure what you mean by fitted/map/reduce. Perhaps some else can answer that part.